# MP4 video as background

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to create something like vine app has.

This is what I got so far:

```
func playVideo() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("WelcomeVideo", ofType: "mp4")
        let pathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        let myPlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: pathURL)
        myPlayer.moviePlayer.repeatMode = .One

        presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(myPlayer)
    }
```

But the problem is that it shows the playbutton and such.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with something like this ?

```
myPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the player does not fit full? http://s27.postimg.org/6asbqntf7/Screen_Shot_2015_11_24_at_13_53_55.png I use code: `moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height/3)` - When removing the `/3`it fits good, but is not on top of the screen.

Comment: try with `myPlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit`